# angular routing: same url but conditional routing

Tags: angularjs

Right now I have a route as follows:

```
.state('tab.simon', {
    url: '/plan/:exerciseId', <== Notice here
    resolve: {
      authenticated: ['djangoAuth', function(djangoAuth){
        return djangoAuth.authenticationStatus();
      }],
    },
    views: {
      'tab-plan': {
        templateUrl: '/templates/simon.html',
        controller: 'simonCtrl',
        data: {
          css: '/css/simon.css'
        }  
      }
    },
    cache: false
  })
```

The value for exerciseId could be 8/9/10/11/12 and for each such route i.e. `/plan/8` or `/plan/9` etc there is a separate controller and corresponding template and a css file.

Write now I had coded it as follows:

```
.state('tab.simon', {
    url: '/plan/8', 
    resolve: {
      authenticated: ['djangoAuth', function(djangoAuth){
        return djangoAuth.authenticationStatus();
      }],
    },
    views: {
      'tab-plan': {
        templateUrl: '/templates/simon.html',
        controller: 'simonCtrl',
        data: {
          css: '/css/simon.css'
        }  
      }
    },
    cache: false
  })

  .state('tab.pinpoint', {
    url: '/plan/9', 
    resolve: {
      authenticated: ['djangoAuth', function(djangoAuth){
        return djangoAuth.authenticationStatus();
      }],
    },
    views: {
      'tab-plan': {
        templateUrl: '/templates/pinpointReaction.html',
        controller: 'pinpointCtrl',
        data: {
          css: '/css/pinpoint.css'
        }  
      }
    },
    cache: false
  })
```

This is not optimum and in this case I can not take advantage of `$stateparams` as with `plan/:exerciseId`

**How can I handle this?**

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how technically it is possible, but logically i solved my problem.

Essentially, Each route has it's own controller so passing `exerciseId` as stateParam wasn't necessary as I initially thought. I could instead hardcode it in my controller like following:

```
$scope.gameType=9
var url = "https://127.0.0.1:8000/api2/games/get_game/" + $scope.gameType + "/";
```

instead of

```
var exerciseType = Number($stateParams.exerciseId);
var url = "https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/exercises/get_exercise/" + exerciseType + "/";
```